# Is it possible to disable Locker Service for LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, locker-service, offline

I'm developing lwc and I'm using api version 56.0 and would like to use indexedDB for offline cashing.

It looks like it's currently not supported.

Is it possible to disable locker service for specific lwc?

I'm cashing large documents with sizes reaches to 50mb so localStorage will not work

Comment: This should be possible with Lightning Web Security. Have you tried enabling that in Setup | Session Settings?

Comment: Yes, this solved the problem. Thanks a million

Comment: Great. I'll add that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable [Lightning Web Security](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.security_lwsec_enable), which causes LWC to work under a far less restricted security model. Make sure you test your org's code to verify everything still works. It's recommended you try this in a Sandbox first.